# Persist session across different technologies

Tags: java, asp.net, tomcat, iis

Say I have 2 web applications. One is on a tomcat server and uses java. Abother is written in ASP.NET and is on an IIS server.

I want users to be able to log in on the IIS web application handling authentication, and if through a link they access a page hosted on my tomcat, I want them to be logged in. Both systems can access any/all databases in the background. I also have reverse proxies (F5 devices) at my disposal. The separate systems How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Generate a signature binding with userID and store it somewhere if some one succeeds in loggin in
2. Add this signature to the url on the IIS web page,and then goes to tomcat pages
3. Validate this signature which stored before and create session by the userID

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use something called Jespa: http://www.ioplex.com/

Here is another SO question regarding this setup:  [Tomcat Integrated Windows Authentication across Multiple Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027333/tomcat-integrated-windows-authentication-across-multiple-domains)